# Is any decorator necessary for using Mobx in React Native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, mobx

I tried to use Mobx to manage state in React Native Project(ADE is Expo).

I have just install Mobx and Mobx-react by npm.

But some article about Mobx I read is mentioning some decorators like legacy and ~~-0.

Now actually my Mobx sample code is working without decorators.

So, I am wondering these decorators are necessary or not in my Project?
In addition to this, if these are necessary, why I should use these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JS decorators are essentially just syntactic sugar which currently are not part of the JS language but some transpilers such as Babel has [integrated](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators) them in their latest implementations. Using them is totally your personal preference just like you can create a complete React app without using the JS classes. They make the code more readable. Since you are using Expo, you don't need to add anything to babel configurations to be able to use them. In my understanding Expo does this for you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
In my case, I am creating mobile app for iOS and Android with Expo and React Native. And in my understanding, decorators is for implementation on each deferent browsers. So, I am wondering these are necessary for mobile apps?

Comment: Decorators are not unique to web development. They are part of the language specification and since you are using Javascript in React Native you can use almost all of its features in mobile development as well.
Browsers evolve at their own pace and since some of them don't support the latest language features right away, you have to find your way around using those features. This isn't the case with React Native.

Comment: I see. So if I don't use decorators, what will be happened ?

Comment: Nothing. There is a way to use mobx without decorators on their website. It's just a matter of personal choice. It's much more verbose when you don't use decorators tho so I will suggest using decorators.